Reference for Gröbner-Shirshov algorithm in free restricted Lie algebras
I am searching for a reference on the Gröbner-Shirshov algorithm specifically for free restricted Lie algebras. I have already consulted the textbook by Bokut et al (Gröbner–Shirshov Bases Normal Forms, Combinatorial and Decision Problems in Algebra)., as well as various papers, but so far, I haven't found a suitable reference.
Given Shirshov's paper "On Free Lie Rings," I suspect there could be an analogous algorithm for the restricted case. If anyone is aware of such a reference, I would greatly appreciate your guidance.

Which text do you refer as "textbook by Bokut et al."?

@YCor Thank you very much for your consideration! I was referring to the book "Gröbner–Shirshov Bases Normal Forms, Combinatorial and Decision Problems in Algebra" (https://doi.org/10.1142/9287).
